# How does LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) inference from `gensim` work for a new data?

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling, inference

I am training my `ldamodel` using `gensim`, and predicting using a test corpus like this `ldamodel[doc_term_matrix_test]`, it works just fine but I don't understand how the prediction is actually done using the trained model (what `ldamodel[doc_term_matrix_test]` is doing).

Here is the code :

```
dictionary2 = corpora.Dictionary(test)
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(train)
dictionary.merge_with(dictionary2)
doc_term_matrix2 = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in test]
doc_term_matrix = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in train]
Lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel
ldamodel = Lda(doc_term_matrix, num_topics=2, id2word = 
dictionary,random_state=100, iterations=50, passes=1)
topics = sorted(ldamodel[doc_term_matrix2],
                key=lambda 
                x:x[1],
                reverse=True)
```

Comment: Please provide some code, as minimal as possible, to better explain your question.

Comment: It definitely does predict new data, and that is usually the main motivation of performing an LDA analysis. If you'd like to see the general intuition before diving into technical details, which I highly recommend, please see my talk from last year: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKydUI_gMhs The prediction of new data is at 23:25.

Comment: thank you for your help FatihAkici, but can you explain how the prediction is done (calculated) using the trained model ?

Comment: Why are you merging two dictionaries? it seems like a data leakage issue to me.

Comment: @FatihAkici why dont you share small code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote from [gensim docs about ldamodel](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html):

> This module allows both LDA model estimation from a training corpus and inference of topic distribution on new, unseen documents.

So apparently, what your code does is not quite "prediction" but rather inference. That is, your trained LDA model yields for every test document `T` an estimation of the topic distribution of `T`.

Comment: I don't know. It might e.g. perform some Maximum Likelihood Estimation of distribution parameters, given the topics that it obtained through training. Why is it important for you to know that?

Comment: but do you know how it inferences ? like how is it calculated and what should i do if i wanted proper prediction

Comment: As I said, I don't know. If it's that important, you could e.g. go through the gensim code. Also, I am not sure what you mean by "prediction", e.g. do you wish to predictively generate a new document? What do you want to predict?

Comment: thank you for your answer,i have to clarify every point for my report..

Comment: I hope this helps then. If so, kindly upvote my answer, tx.

Comment: i mean predicting the topic of unseen documents so i can judge if my ldamodel is doing good, so "inference" is maybe the right term fot that ?

Comment: i did but "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."